# How to retrieve user shares

Tags: rest, linkedin-api

We have a working app that we're hoping to extend to include querying of personal shares via the linkedin rest api, using https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares

Our app has the following scopes provisioned in the developer console (and we're providing these in the auth request): `['r_basicprofile','w_share','rw_company_admin','r_ad_campaigns','rw_organization']`

The http response returns the message

> Access to shares denied

I'm wondering what scope is required to access this api or where I can find the docs to answer my own query?

Comment: Are you able to get personal shares of users? Were you able to succeed?